# Canvas+Javascript water overlay

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make water waves in Javascript on a canvas but there is something wrong.

My idea was making 3 waves with different colors but they overdraw each other.
I was not able figure out where the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <style>

    <!-- 100% area -->
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>

    <script>
      //get window size
      var canvas = document.getElementById( "myCanvas" );
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;   /// equal to window dimension
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

      // get the context
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


      // VARIABLES
      var frameCount=0;
      var N = 30;
      var positionXTeiler= Math.floor(canvas.width/(N-N/2));
      var size = 50;
      var xOffset = 200;
      var colors = [];
      var amplitude = 200;
      var wavesCount = 3;


      var init = function()
      {
        colors.push("rgba(0,0,128,1)");
        colors.push("rgba(0,0,255,1)");
        colors.push("rgba(47,86,233,1)");
      }

      var draw = function() {

        context.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 


        for (i=0; i<N; i++) { 

          for (n=0; n<wavesCount; n++) { 
            var x = amplitude*Math.sin (frameCount*0.02+n*Math.PI/2);
            context.save();
            context.fillStyle = colors[n];
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(positionXTeiler*i+x-xOffset,canvas.height-n*20,size,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();

            context.restore();
          }
        }       
        // count the frame and loop the animation
        frameCount = frameCount+1;
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      };

      // start the loop
      init();
      draw();


    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

My result should look like that + with moving

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I uploaded the wishing output

Comment: Is the problem the fact that the bottom waves disappear ?

Comment: Yes, it should not disappear

Comment: The problem is in the way that you're drawing the waves. What you should do is (1) draw all of the arcs for the most distant wave (2) draw all the arcs for the middle wave (3) draw all the arcs for the closest wave. What you're doing instead is drawing the first arc for all three waves, then the 2nd arc for all 3 etc, etc. Each wave is on it's own 'layer' and must be completed before attempting to draw the next one. :)

Comment: I prefer the bugged one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop the waves and, inside, loop the circles (i.e. invert the two loops).

The goal is to draw all circles of a wave before moving to the next. This way you are making sure that the circles of a wave are drawn on top of the circles of the previous one.

Also, you may want to consider using a time-based increment instead of a frame count. Animation frames are not guaranteed to be regular and their rate depends of the user's system.

```js
//get window size
var canvas = document.getElementById( "myCanvas" );
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;   /// equal to window dimension
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// get the context
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// VARIABLES
var frameCount=0;
var N = 30;
var positionXTeiler= Math.floor(canvas.width/(N-N/2));
var size = 50;
var xOffset = 200;
var colors = [];
var amplitude = 200;
var wavesCount = 3;


var init = function()
{
  colors.push("rgba(0,0,128,1)");
  colors.push("rgba(0,0,255,1)");
  colors.push("rgba(47,86,233,1)");
}

var draw = function() {
  context.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
  for (n=wavesCount-1; n>=0; n--) { 
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) { 
      var x = amplitude*Math.sin (frameCount*0.02+n*Math.PI/2);
      context.save();
      context.fillStyle = colors[n];
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(positionXTeiler*i+x-xOffset,canvas.height-n*20,size,0,Math.PI*2,true);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
      context.restore();
    }
  }       
  // count the frame and loop the animation
  frameCount = frameCount+1;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

// start the loop
init();
draw();
```

```css
<!-- 100% area -->
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you adapt the example to show just a simple slow up/down movement of the waves?

Comment: If you want to go slower you can adjust the frameCount increment, e.g. `frameCount = frameCount+.3`. Of course it isn't a frame count anymore..

Comment: As I said, the best would be to switch to a time-based increment.

Comment: okay, but I wanted an up/down movement instead of left/right. ideally based on a sine-function to smooth it..

Comment: Oh. I only have my phone available, but you should be able to make that work by playing a bit with the 2 first arguments of `context.arc`.